# calculate the average for every year from a text file in python

Tags: python

So this is my text file and i want to calculate the average for every year:

```
1969    324.000
1970    330.190
1970    326.720
1970    327.130
1971    326.970
1971    331.200
1971    329.430
1971    335.770
1971    337.600
```

And this is my Code that i got from another question but it keeps erroring:

```
In[2]: result = {}
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
       for line in f:
       year, num = line.split()
       year = int(year)
       num = float(num)
       try:
           result[year].append(num)
       except KeyError:
           result[year] = [num]

In[3]: for k, v in sorted(result.items()):
   print('Year: {}\tAverage: {:.2f}'.format(k, sum(v) / len(v)))
```

My error: Expected a indent block

Comment: Your way is just fine.

Comment: I Keep getting the error: Expected a indent block

Comment: Yoiu have improper indentation of a block after 'for line in f:'

Comment: How do i fix that

Comment: in python indentation matters, it indicates what code is in what block. you get the error because you haven't indented any code for the `for line in f:` so its expecting an indented block that isn't there. I'm voting to close this as a typographical error

Comment: @Hero_of_Hell, did one of the below answers help? If so, please accept one (green tick on left) or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like you don't intend the line after for loop.

```
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
       year, num = line.split()
       ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to `pandas`, the library offers an optimized solution.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

mystr = StringIO("""1969    324.000
1970    330.190
1970    326.720
1970    327.130
1971    326.970
1971    331.200
1971    329.430
1971    335.770
1971    337.600""")

df = pd.read_csv(mystr, header=None, names=['Year', 'Amount'],
                 delim_whitespace=True)

res = df.groupby('Year')['Amount'].mean().to_dict()
```

Result:

```
{1969: 324.0, 1970: 328.01333333333338, 1971: 332.19400000000007}
```